# GreenDroid ActionBar error

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, greendroid

I am trying create a simple tab activity using GreenDroid, below is my code

```
public class TabBarActivity extends GDTabActivity {

    private static final String TAB1 = "tab_one";
    private static final String TAB2 = "tab_two";
    private static final String TAB3 = "tab_three";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle("Screen 2");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, JobActivity.class);
        addTab(TAB1, "Tab One", intent);

        intent = new Intent(this, ContactListActivity.class);    
        addTab(TAB2, "Tab Two", intent);

        intent = new Intent(this, ParentActivity.class);
        addTab(TAB3, "Tab Three", intent);
    }


}
```

I am getting following error...

09-11 11:18:37.571: W/dalvikvm(20395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ee9438)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cybergeniesolutions.bb/com.cybergeniesolutions.bb.TabBarActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class greendroid.widget.ActionBar
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class greendroid.widget.ActionBar
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at greendroid.app.GDTabActivity.onCreate(GDTabActivity.java:52)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at com.cybergeniesolutions.bb.TabBarActivity.onCreate(TabBarActivity.java:18)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    ... 11 more
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    ... 23 more
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01002a a=-1}
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2239)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.View.(View.java:3419)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:432)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:176)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.(LinearLayout.java:172)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at greendroid.widget.ActionBar.(ActionBar.java:134)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    at greendroid.widget.ActionBar.(ActionBar.java:130)
09-11 11:18:37.601: E/AndroidRuntime(20395):    ... 26 more